# Does changing A record IP address affect MX records?

Tags: dns, mx

Suppose you have the following A record:

```
example.com. 3599 IN A 192.0.2.78
```

And these MX records:

```
example.com. 997 IN MX 10 mx01.1and1.co.uk.example.
example.com. 997 IN MX 10 mx00.1and1.co.uk.example.
```

And you then changed the IP address for the A record to a non 1&1 ip address (so that the website could be hosted on an external hosting), would that affect the MX records or mess up the email in any way?

Comment: It does not affect the MX records. However, if your email client is set up to send or receive email via `example.com`, then making the change *will* disrupt your ability to send/receive email. You can work around this issue by setting up a new A record like `host.example.com. 3599 IN A 192.0.2.78`, and then reconfiguring your email client to send/receive email via `host.example.com` instead of `example.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add some more info here as an explainer for future visitors:

The A record tells the internet where to find the web site for a domain.

The MX record tell the internet which service is handling email.

A basic setup might be to have an A record

```
example.com. 3599 IN A 111.123.456.78
```

and then *mail.example.com* points to the same IP address with an A record

```
mail.example.com. 3599 IN A 111.123.456.78
```

or a CNAME record

```
mail.example.com. 3599 IN CNAME example.com
```

Then the MX record set up would be

```
example.com. 997 IN MX 10 mail.example.com
```

However, if the MX record was set up as Marc (the OP) has it

```
example.com. 997 IN MX 10 mx00.1and1.co.uk.
```

then the *mail.example.com* record would be redundant as the server managing DNS would not be handling email at all.

Answer (score 4):

No, email would not be affected.

The only situation where changing an A record would affect email was if you were changing an A record like `mail.example.com` which your MX records were pointing at.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. So if the target of the mx records (mx01.1and1.co.uk.) was actually (mail.example.com.) it would affect it, otherwise it wouldn't. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct..